# AngularJs Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Key: undefined

Tags: angularjs

Ive been trying to solve this angular ng-repeat problem but getting this error

> Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Repeater: document in project.documentConfig.documents track by document.Name key: undefined

Html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="project in translatorHubConfig.projects">
    <td>{{ project.ProjectName }}</td>
    <td>{{ project.SourceLanguage }}</td>
    <td>{{ project.TargetLanguage }}</td>
    <td>{{ project.Status }}</td>
    <td>
        <div ng-repeat="document in project.documentConfig.documents track by document.Name">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" value="{{document.Name}}" ng-model="project.documentConfig.documents" />
                <a ng-href="{{document.documentUrl}}" style="cursor: pointer;">{{ document.Name }}</a>
            </label>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td><span class="train-project" ng-click="TrainProject(project.ProjectName, project.documentConfig.documents)" /></td>
</tr>
```

If i change it to track by $index

```
<td>
    <div ng-repeat="document in project.documentConfig.documents track by $index">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" value="{{document.Name}}" ng-model="project.documentConfig.documents" />
            <a ng-href="{{document.documentUrl}}" style="cursor: pointer;">{{ document.Name }}</a>
        </label>
    </div>
</td>
```

Each time that i click on radio button will produce this:

[image: Multiple radiobutton is created when click]

Response:

```
{projects: Array(3), Success: true, StatusMessage: "", PageNumber: 0, PageSize: 0, …}
PageNumber:0
PageSize:0
StatusMessage:""
Success:true
TotalPages:1
projects:Array(3)
0:{ProjectName: "DemoTranslatorHub", ProjectLabel: null, DisplayName: "DemoTranslatorHub", SourceLanguage: "English", TargetLanguage: "Korean", …}
1:{ProjectName: "DemoTranslatorHub_En_Es", ProjectLabel: null, DisplayName: "DemoTranslatorHub_En_Es", SourceLanguage: "English", TargetLanguage: "Spanish", …}
2:{ProjectName: "DemoTranslatorHub_En_Ja", ProjectLabel: null, DisplayName: "DemoTranslatorHub_En_Ja", SourceLanguage: "English", TargetLanguage: "Japanese", …}
length:3
```

I am not quite sure what is it i am doing it wrongly. 
Tqvm in advanced.

Comment: The `ng-model="project.documentConfig.documents"` is stomping on `ng-repeat="document in project.documentConfig.documents`.

Comment: can you create a plunker or code pen of your code? It will be blazing fast resolve it.

Answer (score 3):

Use `track by $index` in ng-repeat or you can use a key that have all unique values.

Answer (score 0):

You can't track NG repeater with a key that will get repeated values, so the correct way is to use $index as you did or maybe, if documents don't have duplicated objects, there is no need to track. But reading the error it's like some of the objects in array have undefined 'name' key, so that's why you got empty radio buttons. I didn't get your question, what did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but problem is ng-model="project.documentConfig.documents"
when you click radio button project.documentConfig.documents gets updated and ng-repeat tries to rerender the html according to project.documentConfig.documents